# How can I solve $\inf_{x \in X} x^T(Ax + b) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i)$ in a closed form depending on projection?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve the minimization problem

$$\inf_{x \in X} x^T(Ax + b) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i)$$

where $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set. And $A$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix. The optimality conditions give me something like

$$-b \in 2Ax + \vec{1} + L(x) + N_X(x)$$

where $L(x)$ represents the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ obtained by taking the elementwise logarithm of $x$; i.e., $[L(x)]_i=\log x_i$.

The problem is how do I take that cone out of the inclusion. If there wasn't that log term it would become a projection on the set $X$. Is there a trick to make this as a projection on $X$ of other vector or something?

I'd appreciate any help or any paper/book reference where there's some information about this kind of problem

Comment: There is no closed form. You have to solve this numerically, even if $X\equiv\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I see. In this case do you know where can I find info on numerically solving this?

Comment: I would recommend looking into CVX (incidentally, it is partially authored by the previous commenter): http://cvxr.com/cvx/.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your inclusion
$$-b \in 2Ax + \vec{1} + L(x) + N_X(x),$$
we can add $x$ on both sides and re-arrange to get:

$$x-2Ax-\vec{1}-L(x)-b \in (I+N_X)(x),$$
where $I$ denotes the identity operator $x\mapsto x$.
We can now invert to get 
$$x = P_X\big(x-2Ax-\vec{1}-L(x)-b\big).$$
This reformulation takes the normal cone operator out of
your problem and converts it to a fixed point problem
that you might try to approach with fixed-point theoretic
algorithms.